# Making a simple POST request with the pastebin API

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, pastebin

I was wondering how I would be able to make a post request to pastebin.com. They have an easy to understand [API documentation](https://pastebin.com/api#2), but whenever I run a simple POST request I always get `Bad API request, invalid api_option`.

I'm using the bear minimum required to make the request, I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

`var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("POST", "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php?api_dev_key=mykey&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=hi", false);
request.send();
request.response;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I made it work like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("POST", "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", true);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.send("api_dev_key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&api_option=paste&api_paste_private=0&api_paste_name=myname.js&api_paste_expire_date=10M&api_paste_format=javascript&api_paste_code=random");
```

I hope it helps