# Can't make a request to Pastebin API

Tags: javascript, api, pastebin

I'm trying to send an API request to Pastebin.com: [doc](https://pastebin.com/doc_api)

```
let dev_key = 'XXXX';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php',
    data: {
        api_dev_key: dev_key,
        api_option: 'paste',
        api_paste_code: 'test'
    },
    success: response => {
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

but it returns me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Code looks ok to me, can you share the response from your network tab? That error suggests there was a response, it’s just missing the header which tells the browser it’s ok for javascript to access it. You might find a clue in the response as to why the server didn’t like the POST request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430229/making-a-simple-post-request-with-the-pastebin-api

Comment: At minimum, you can't access web content using pages served from `file://` urls. You'll need host this on an `https://` capable web server (even a local one) for this code to work.